# a Struck constant won't allow me to create a calendar

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a calendar and have been following a tutorial on YouTube `calendar ruby on rails` first video. once I inputted the code I had an error,

> uninitialized constant CalenderHelper::Struck

the code is;

```
module CalenderHelper
def calender(date = Date.today, &block)
    Calender.new(self, date, block).table
end

**class Calender < Struck.new(:view, :date, :callback)**
    HEADER = %w[Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday]
    START_DAY = :sunday 

    delegate :content_tag, to: :view

def table
    content_tag :table, class: "calender" do
        header + week_rows
    end
end

def header
    content_tag :tr do
    HEADER.map { |day| content_tag :th, day }.join.html_safe
    end
end

def week_rows
    week.map do |week|
        content_tag :tr do
            week.map { |day| day_cell(day) }.join.html_safe
        end
    end.join.html_safe
end

def day_cell(day)
    content_tag :td, view.capture(day, &callback), class: day_classes(day)
end

def day_classes(day)
    classes = []
    classes << "today" if day == Date.today
    classes << "notmonth" if day.month != date.month
    classes.empty? ? nil : classes.join(" ")
end

def weeks 
    first = date.beginning_of_month.beginning_of_week(START_DAY)
    last = date.end_of_month.end_of_week(START_DAY)
    (first..last).to_a.in_groups_of(7)
    end
end
end
```

line with the error is marker with starts on each side

Answer (score 1):

You have a small spelling mistake:

You want to call the [Struct](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Struct.html) class, not Struck.

your line should be:

```rb
class Calendar < Struct.new(:view, :date, :callback)
    # the rest of the code
end
```

Hope that helps